# TextField text not displaying from UIPopOverView

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, uitextfield, uipopovercontroller

I have a `UITextField` on main `ViewController` and once I touch down the Textfield `UIPopOverController` with `UIPickerView` opens which is from other class.now I want when I select any value in `Pickerview` of `popovercontroller` the selected value should display as `UITextfield text` and In main `Viewcontroller` when I pick any value in `Pickerview` a method calls to print `UITextfield text` but `textfield.text` comes always null. but I used the `Appdelegate sharedAppdeledate`which give me value on tapping on pickerview but when i used it to text the textfield it gets null. what should I Do.

and I want to add value on the UITextfield without removing the top view which is pickerview

Comment: please show us some code..

Comment: You could create a custom delegate to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass your parent class object to your popovercontroller class and you'll be able to have access of the parent class property in child class and then you'll be able to set your textfield value selection on picker from popovercontroller class

Comment: Thanks. I passed the textfield.text value in popovercontroller then its reflecting .. but the when i pass into the parent class then textfield value comes ..null .. can you please explain me this

Comment: add this code in your popovercontroller class

    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    objParent.txtState.text = [arrItems objectAtIndex:row];
}

here objParent is an object of your parent class and txtState is your textfield. i think this should work for you else you need to paste some code so that i can look at your condition and give you the solution thanks.